# New Character in Chess game

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, chessboard

I having problem to solve the below question:

> Given $2020\times 2020$ chessboard, what is the maximum number of warriors you can put on its cells such that no two warriors attack each other.
>   Warrior is a special chess piece which can move either:
>
> - $3$ steps forward and one step sideways in any direction, or
> - $2$ steps forward and $2$ steps sideways in any direction.

Answer Given: 2020 *505

Got Solution from one friend:
Strategy: Put the warriors in $(4k+1)$ columns.

Proof 1)We can easily notice that warriors can't attack warriors in his own column. So we can arrange the warriors in the above mentioned arrangement.
2) The warriors of $(4k+1)$column can attack warriors of $4k,4k-1,4k-2$ columns . So we can't put the warriors in those cells.

So the maximum number of warriors that can be put is $2020 \times 505$

Comment: Every fourth row can be filled with warriors and none would attack each other. This gives the $2020\times 505$ which is the given answer. You just need to prove there is not a better configuration.

Comment: I am confused now.  Why can't we fill the warriors every third row?  Under the given rule, if they are all facing the same way, then they are not attacking each other, right?  So you can do this with $2020\times\left\lceil\frac{2020}{3}\right\rceil$ warriors.  Can the pieces turn left/right to attack one another?

Comment: In chess, the only piece that has a facing is the pawn. No other piece does. Unless you specify that a piece has a facing, it is not clear that it does. So, if "forward" is relative, then in the middle of the board, a warrior is attacking $12$ squares, not $2$ as your diagram shows. If warriors have a facing, you should include that in their description.

Comment: But i can't change real question which i got ; it is not made by me

Comment: If you cannot change the question, then you must make an assumption. If the problem does not specify, then you can choose that warriors do not have a facing, "forward" is relative, and a warrior can attack at most $12$ squares. Or you can choose that warriors do have a facing, and a warrior can attack at most $4$ squares.

Comment: Which of the numbered squares can the warrior at $0$ attack, assuming that the warrior is currently facing upwards?  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&& &&& &&\\
\hline
&&&4 &&3& &&
\\
\hline
&&5& &&& 2&&
\\
\hline
&6&& &&& &1&
\\
\hline
&&& &0&& &&
\\
\hline
&7&& &&& &12&
\\
\hline
&&8& &&& 11&
\\
\hline
&&& 9&&10& &
\\
\hline
&&& &&& &
\\
\hline
\end{array}$$  Is the answer just the four squares $2,3,4,5$, or all of the twelve numbered squares?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe actually there are other patterns, some of them yield same and some better results. I found a 5x6 pattern that can hold 8 pawns. So the board can be filled with 8/30 = 4/15 which is better than the 1/4 of the simple pattern.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I did not say that every fourth row filled was the solution. I said that yields the number that is at the bottom of the post as the "Answer Given". Clearly if you are finding better configurations, then the given answer is probably wrong.

Comment: What you added in the question is not a proof that the maximum is 2020*505. It only shows that you can place 2020*505 warriors. As my answer shows, you can put more than that. And my answer is not a proof either for the mx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A configuration that yields a better fill than the 1/4 of the given answer:

Rectangles of 5x6 that have 8 squares with a "warrior", yielding a 8/30 fill:

Blue = warrior
Yellow = empty

[image]

2020 is not exactly divided by 6 so you'll have space on one side filled partially so the exact fill value is not 8/30 - but slightly more!

---

The 2020 x 2016 can be filled with $8 / 15 - 1 / 4 = 1 / 60$ more warriors than the simple solution and the remaining 2020 x 4 can be filled with $11 / 40 - 1 / 4 = 1 / 40$ more warriors, resulting in:

$2020 * 2016 / 60 + 2020 * 4 / 40 = 68074$ more warriors than the simple pattern.

simple pattern: $2020 * 505 = 1020100$

pattern above: $1020100 + 68074 = 1088174$

---

**Variant problem**

**Addition** for the problem **variant**, where the warriors can face any of 4 directions and they attack only 4 cells forward (the ones numbered 2,3,4,5 in the image)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline &&& &&& &&\\ \hline &&&4 &&3& && \\ \hline &&5& &&& 2&& \\ \hline &6&& &&& &1& \\ \hline &&& &0&& && \\ \hline &7&& &&& &12& \\ \hline &&8& &&& 11& \\ \hline &&& 9&&10& & \\ \hline &&& &&& & \\ \hline \end{array}
$$

The best fill I could find is 1/2 (8 cells out of 16 in a 4x4 pattern). The arrows show which direction the warriors should be facing:

[image]

Comment: If each warrior has a facing (see the discussion under the question), do you think you can find a better configuration than the $1/3$ fill I gave in one of my comments?  I think you can split this part into two different questions: (1) all must face the same way, and (2) each can choose its own facing.  If you can find a better configuration, please write another answer, so I can upvote again.  Cheers!

Comment: I believe that in scenario (1), my 1/3 fill configuration is optimal or very close to optimal.  However, I think there are better configurations in scenario (2).

Comment: @WETutorialSchool possibly yes. It would also depend what facing means. Do we define the attack squares to be 2,3,4,5 as in your comment or 1,2,3,4,5,6 or etc...

Comment: I think according to the OP's wording, if the warrior at $0$ is facing upwards, it can only attack $2,3,4,5$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool yeah, that's  a valid reading if we consider the pawns facing. In general though we could choose arbitrary subsets. The less number of moves that a pawn has, the more fill factor we can hope to achieve. I was thinking of the general problem and I don't think there's an easy general solution.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I found a solution with 1/2 fill for the facing variant (with 2,3,4,5). Edited in the answer as I can't add another.

Comment: Beautiful!  I wish I could upvote twice!

Comment: @WETutorialSchool simpler pattern with 1/2 fill: 1st row facing UP, 2nd row facing DOWN, 3-4t rows.empty, repeat. ;)